# Is it known in human psychology that when you comment on something negatively but objectively, people may associate the negativity with YOU?

Tags: psychology

I just heard that when you criticize something objectively and even when other people agree that it is true, the people that heard your criticism may actually associate this negativity with YOU. What is this phenomenon called?

For example, if you comment on a metropolitan city, people tend to be impersonal, I heard people hearing your comment actually may associate "impersonal" with *you*. That actually is opposite to what might be expected, because if I mention people are impersonal, it should imply that I hope for the situation to be more personable, which mean I am not impersonal. So this is a big surprise if it is in fact true.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. *"I heard people hearing your comment actually may associate "impersonal" with you."* You heard from where?

Comment: @ChrisRogers: Sounds like Mum effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Tesser#Interpersonal_Communication:_The_Mum_Effect

Comment: @ChrisRogers it was from a YouTube video talking about interpersonal characteristics. It mentioned about this but didn't go too deeply into in.

Comment: @nopole please include a link to the YouTube video, and state who it is that authored it.

Comment: Is this related to *Don't shoot the messenger*?